# AWS CLI expression: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I run the query below and it works.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups \
          --filters Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=21 Name=ip-permission.to-Port,Values=21  \
          --query 'SecurityGroups[].[Tags[?Key==`Owner`] | [0].Value, GroupId]' \
          --output text
```

But trying to get security groups that have open traffic for all and the value of the `Tag=Owner`, I run this and get jmespath error.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.protocol,Values=-1 --query SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?IpProtocol == '-1' && contains(IpRanges[].CidrIp,'0.0.0.0/0')]].[Tags[?Key==`Owner`] | [0].Value, GroupId]' --output=text
```

> Bad value for --query SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?IpProtocol == -1 && contains(IpRanges[].CidrIp,0.0.0.0/0)]].[Tags[?Key==`Owner`] | [0].Value, GroupId]: Bad jmespath expression: Unknown token /:""

Comment: Did you forget one apostrophe in front of SecurityGroups?

Comment: Adding that similar error. The below works. But when I try to get the Owner tag and its value, it fails

aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters "Name=ip-permission.protocol,Values=-1" --query "SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?IpProtocol == '-1' && contains(IpRanges[].CidrIp,'0.0.0.0/0')]].GroupId" --output=text

Comment: The quotes always confuse me with AWS CLI and JMESPATH. Try using different quotes rather than back-ticks. And/or try wrapping the expression in different quotes. It can be annoying at times. For example: `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions[?IpProtocol == "-1" && contains(IpRanges[].CidrIp,"0.0.0.0/0")]].[Tags[?Key=="Owner"] | [0].Value, GroupId]'` That seemed to work on my Mac under zsh.

Answer (score 3):

I had to wrap the chars that threw an error in a 'quote' symbol and successfully retrieved an output afterwards:

```
    aws rds describe-db-instances \
  --query "*[].[dbidentifier,'dbidentifier.cx32323sss6ib.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com','5432',admin]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer [Steampipe](https://steampipe.io), a CLI that can query AWS resources using SQL. It can be more verbose than JMES, but is much easier to read and more flexible to query.

Here is your first query as SQL using the [aws_vpc_security_group_rule](https://hub.steampipe.io/plugins/turbot/aws/tables/aws_vpc_security_group_rule) table:

```
select
  sg.tags ->> 'Owner' as owner,
  sg.group_id
from
  aws_vpc_security_group as sg
  join aws_vpc_security_group_rule as rule on sg.group_id = rule.group_id
where
  rule.type = 'ingress'
  and from_port = 22
  and to_port = 22;
```

And here is a query to find the open ports:

```
select
  sg.tags->>'Owner',
  sg.group_id
from
  aws_vpc_security_group as sg
  join aws_vpc_security_group_rule as rule on sg.group_id = rule.group_id
where
  rule.type = 'ingress'
  and rule.ip_protocol = '-1'
  and rule.cidr_ip = '0.0.0.0/0'
```

Comment: Nathan. That looks promising. Let me check it out..thx !